# what is the most reliable way of changing the window size of console using c+?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I am coding in c++ and trying to set/change the window size of the console.
I have found a way to do this, however it doesn't work on my friend's PC but it does work on mine.

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(console, &r); 

    MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 800, 600, TRUE); 
    while(1){
        cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is the code I used to set the window size of the console, but it doesn't work on my friend's computer. This makes me feel like it will be unreliable since I will need it for my GCSE practical exam.

I need to find another way to do this, please help.

edit..
im animating ascii art and stuff like that, so when it shows and the dimensions aren't right, the ascii art is distorted. This also happens with the sentences i output, i align them in the centre in code but it gets distorted as well.

```
MoveWindow()
getlasterror()
```

Outputs true
and no error outputs

Also the reason why im doing c++ console is because this is what my school is doing for computer science GCSE. I know its probably the worst language and I'd rather do c# form on visal studio but my school wont give me choice.

Me and my friend both 64 bit operating system with windows 10

Comment: Does `MoveWindow()` return true or false on your friend's PC? If false, what does `GetLastError()` return? But, why do you need to do this at all? Your app does not own the console window, it may be sharing the window with other apps, so it has no business messing with the window. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: You do zero error checking. If you use an API call, **always** check the return value, and review the documentation to see what the return values mean and whether failures use `GetLastError` to provide more information. Just blindly calling functions and assuming they succeed is a recipe for failure. If you check the return values properly instead of just ignoring them, you'll be much better off (and much happier).

Comment: Why are you [targeting Windows 2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019)? It's 2019 now. What operating system do you and your friend run? How you build this program? Give _details_.